# How do I add mass comments into Windows Command prompt?

Tags: python, windows, comments, command-prompt

I have a lot of text I would like to add as a comment. For example, I want to put the enitre help section of CHKDSK:

```
Checks a disk and displays a status report.


CHKDSK [volume[[path]filename]]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:size]] [/B] [/scan] [/spotfix]


  volume              Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
                      mount point, or volume name.
  filename            FAT/FAT32 only: Specifies the files to check for
                      fragmentation.
  /F                  Fixes errors on the disk.
  /V                  On FAT/FAT32: Displays the full path and name of every
                      file on the disk.
                      On NTFS: Displays cleanup messages if any.
  /R                  Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information
                      (implies /F, when /scan not specified).
  /L:size             NTFS only:  Changes the log file size to the specified
                      number of kilobytes.  If size is not specified, displays
                      current size.
  /X                  Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary.
                      All opened handles to the volume would then be invalid
                      (implies /F).
  /I                  NTFS only: Performs a less vigorous check of index
                      entries.
  /C                  NTFS only: Skips checking of cycles within the folder
                      structure.
  /B                  NTFS only: Re-evaluates bad clusters on the volume
                      (implies /R)
  /scan               NTFS only: Runs a online scan on the volume
  /forceofflinefix    NTFS only: (Must be used with "/scan")
                      Bypass all online repair; all defects found
                      are queued for offline repair (i.e. "chkdsk /spotfix").
  /perf               NTFS only: (Must be used with "/scan")
                      Uses more system resources to complete a scan as fast as
                      possible. This may have a negative performance impact on
                      other tasks running on the system.
  /spotfix            NTFS only: Runs spot fixing on the volume
  /sdcleanup          NTFS only: Garbage collect unneeded security descriptor
                      data (implies /F).
  /offlinescanandfix  Runs an offline scan and fix on the volume.
  /freeorphanedchains FAT/FAT32/exFAT only: Frees any orphaned cluster chains
                      instead of recovering their contents.
  /markclean          FAT/FAT32/exFAT only: Marks the volume clean if no
                      corruption was detected, even if /F was not specified.

The /I or /C switch reduces the amount of time required to run Chkdsk by
skipping certain checks of the volume.
```

However, it is very annoying (and time-consuming) to have to put `rem` tags on the front of every line of code, like:

```
rem Checks a disk and displays a status report.


rem CHKDSK [volume[[path]filename]]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:size]] [/B] [/scan] [/spotfix]


rem   volume              Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
rem                       mount point, or volume name.
rem   filename            FAT/FAT32 only: Specifies the files to check for
rem                       fragmentation.
rem   /F                  Fixes errors on the disk.
rem   /V                  On FAT/FAT32: Displays the full path and name of every
rem                       file on the disk.
rem                       On NTFS: Displays cleanup messages if any.
rem   /R                  Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information
rem                       (implies /F, when /scan not specified).
rem   /L:size             NTFS only:  Changes the log file size to the specified
rem                       number of kilobytes.  If size is not specified, displays
rem                       current size.
rem   /X                  Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary.
rem                       All opened handles to the volume would then be invalid
rem                       (implies /F).
rem   /I                  NTFS only: Performs a less vigorous check of index
rem                       entries.
rem   /C                  NTFS only: Skips checking of cycles within the folder
rem                       structure.
rem   /B                  NTFS only: Re-evaluates bad clusters on the volume
rem                       (implies /R)
rem   /scan               NTFS only: Runs a online scan on the volume
rem   /forceofflinefix    NTFS only: (Must be used with "/scan")
rem                       Bypass all online repair; all defects found
rem                       are queued for offline repair (i.e. "chkdsk /spotfix").
rem   /perf               NTFS only: (Must be used with "/scan")
rem                       Uses more system resources to complete a scan as fast as
rem                       possible. This may have a negative performance impact on
rem                       other tasks running on the system.
rem   /spotfix            NTFS only: Runs spot fixing on the volume
rem   /sdcleanup          NTFS only: Garbage collect unneeded security descriptor
rem                       data (implies /F).
rem   /offlinescanandfix  Runs an offline scan and fix on the volume.
rem   /freeorphanedchains FAT/FAT32/exFAT only: Frees any orphaned cluster chains
rem                       instead of recovering their contents.
rem   /markclean          FAT/FAT32/exFAT only: Marks the volume clean if no
rem                       corruption was detected, even if /F was not specified.

rem The /I or /C switch reduces the amount of time required to run Chkdsk by
rem skipping certain checks of the volume.
```

Is there a way I could mass comment code (like `""" comment here, can be multiple lines"""`in Python?)

Comment: You seem to already know that """ can be used to mass comment Python code.  Please explain what that has to do with adding a mass comment to the windows command prompt.

Comment: This is a bit nuts, but you can add a unique label such as `:end_comment1` on the line just after the multi-line comment. Then on  the line just before the comment add a `goto end_comment1` statement. It appears that cmd doesn't even try to parse the lines in between as valid syntax. It just scans ahead until it finds the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do if you use Vim:

1. Move to the first column of the first line you want to comment.
2. Press `<C-v>` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to enter block select mode.
3. Move the selection to the first column of the last line you want to comment.
4. Type `Irem<esc>` (Insert, type rem, back to normal mode).

Alternatively, since you seem to be familiar with Python, you could pipe it through this script, then copy the output:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write("rem " + line)
```

`CHKDSK /? | python3 comment.py`

Comment: Not working. I just get `'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
`

Comment: It might be different to run python on windows; I don't have a windows machine to try it on.

Comment: I see the problem. You should try Windows!

Comment: I fixed it! Just use py instead of python3